# having problems to deserialize java object in groovy

Tags: java, grails, groovy, deserialization

I am developing an application in Groovy/Grails, which supposed to process some data from the legacy database. One of the columns in one of processed tables has a BLOB type and it stores an object serialized in Java with the writeObject() method.
I can read an instance of the domain object, but when I am trying to deserialize the field with the following code:

```
    def stream = new ObjectInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(instance.body))
    TargetRequest request = (TargetRequest)stream.readObject()
    stream.close()
```

it blows on the second line (readObject) with

> > ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - ClassNotFoundException
> >     occurred when processing request

TargetRequest is my Groovy replica of legacy Java object but the message is asking for the original (legacy) class. I added corresponding JAR file as a runtime dependency to my project, but it is still cannot find it.
Here is the stack trace:

```
    Line | Method
->>  366 | run                in java.net.URLClassLoader$1
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    355 | run                in     ''
|    354 | findClass . . . .  in java.net.URLClassLoader
|    425 | loadClass          in java.lang.ClassLoader
|    358 | loadClass . . . .  in     ''
|    270 | forName            in java.lang.Class
|    625 | resolveClass . . . in java.io.ObjectInputStream
|   1612 | readNonProxyDesc   in     ''
|   1517 | readClassDesc . .  in     ''
|   1771 | readOrdinaryObject in     ''
|   1350 | readObject0 . . .  in     ''
|    370 | readObject         in     ''
|     33 | $tt__doFormat . .  in com.abc.def.xyz.DataFormattingService
|     24 | $tt__formatData   in     ''
|     12 | index . . . . . .  in com.abc.def.xyz.DataFormattingServiceController
|    198 | doFilter           in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter
|     63 | doFilter . . . . . in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter
|   1145 | runWorker          in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . . . . .  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    744 | run                in java.lang.Thread
```

Line #33 in that stack trace points to the line of code mentioned above.
Investigating the problem I added following line to the code before readObject call

```
TargetRequest targetRequest = Class.forName('com.ijk.mln.domain.TargetRequest').newInstance()
```

The class was loaded successfully and object was instantiated. Why it cannot load the very same class on the next line is beyond me. I am at my wits end. Just don't have any more ideas.

If anyone can help me on this problem, I would appreciate it very much.

Comment: Is this in a controller? If so don't name your `TargetRequest` `request` try using `targetRequest` instead. `request` is reserved in a Grails controller. See if that helps. Also, make sure `TargetRequest` is in the same package as your controller or you have imported it.

Comment: No, it is in the service, not in the controller.
However, I did change the name but result is the same.

Comment: What do you mean by "Groovy replica"? Groovy code can happily load plain Java classes so there's no need to "replicate" anything, just use the original Java class directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give a try on this:

```
new ByteArrayInputStream(instance.body).withObjectInputStream(getClass().classLoader) { is ->
    TargetRequest targetRequest = (TargetRequest)is.readObject()
}
```

This way classloader will aware of serialized class type.

---

Adding additional information based on my understanding for the user comment:

Grails uses custom classloaders. Child classLoader can find the class loaded in parent classLoader but not vice versa. So once we supply a classLoader, it uses supplied one instead of default.

For example using following code snippet in the application:

```
def cl = getClass().classLoader
log.debug "Child ClassLoader ==> ${cl}"

while(cl.parent){
    log.debug "==> ${cl.parent}"
    cl = cl.parent
}
```

Will produce similar output like below:

```
Child ClassLoader ==> java.net.URLClassLoader@162ffbfc
==> org.grails.launcher.rootloader.RootLoader@12f483b4
==> sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@6fafc4c2
==> sun.misc.Launcher$ExtClassLoader@7c9ed5d6
```

Comment: That is a solution. It works. However, I still do not understand why original code does not work. D.oes enclosures use a different classloader

Comment: Added few more details based on my understanding. Also SO members can chime-in to add more info :)